# Flutter & Android Studio: Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to develop an app which works with firebase. I am not a professional of coding.

Actually, my app is working well on the emulator but I get an error message as you can see below:

```
W/DynamiteModule(11855): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(11855): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(11855): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/DynamiteModule(11855): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(11855): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(11855): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

And you can see my dependencies below:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
  image: ^2.0.7
  animator: 0.1.4
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+7
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.3
  timeago: 2.0.17
  cached_network_image:
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  geolocator: 5.0.1
  uuid: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  path_provider: ^1.6.16
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0
  firebase_storage: ^4.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.0
```

In addition to providerinstaller issue above when I try to upload an image with camera, I get additional error below:

```
E/flutter (11855): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'path' was called on null.
E/flutter (11855): Receiver: null
E/flutter (11855): Tried calling: path
E/flutter (11855): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter (11855): #1      _UploadPageState.pickImageFromGallery (package:buddiesgram/pages/UploadPage.dart:37:38)
E/flutter (11855): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11855): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992:19)
E/flutter (11855): #3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098:38)
E/flutter (11855): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
E/flutter (11855): #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
E/flutter (11855): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
E/flutter (11855): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:219:7)
E/flutter (11855): #8      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:477:9)
E/flutter (11855): #9      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:78:12)
E/flutter (11855): #10     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:124:9)
E/flutter (11855): #11     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter (11855): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:18)
E/flutter (11855): #13     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:108:7)
E/flutter (11855): #14     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:220:19)
E/flutter (11855): #15     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
E/flutter (11855): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
E/flutter (11855): #17     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
E/flutter (11855): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
E/flutter (11855): #19     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (11855): #20     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (11855): #21     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (11855): #22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
E/flutter (11855): #23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
E/flutter (11855):
```

You can see my code of my upload page below:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class UploadPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UploadPageState createState() => _UploadPageState();
}

class _UploadPageState extends State<UploadPage> {

  PickedFile file;

  captureImageWithCamera() async {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile imageFile = await picker.getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxHeight: 680,
      maxWidth: 970,
    );
    imageFile = PickedFile(imageFile.path);
    setState(() {
      this.file = imageFile;
    });
  }

  pickImageFromGallery() async {

    Navigator.pop(context);
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile imageFile = await picker.getImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxHeight: 680,
      maxWidth: 970,
    );
    imageFile = PickedFile(imageFile.path);
    setState(() {
      this.file = imageFile;
    });
  }

  takeImage(mContext){
    return showDialog(
        context: mContext,
        builder: (context){
          return SimpleDialog(
            title: Text("New Post", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            children: [
              SimpleDialogOption(
                child: Text("Capture image with camera", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                onPressed: captureImageWithCamera,
              ),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                child: Text("Select image from gallery", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                onPressed: pickImageFromGallery,
              ),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                child: Text("Cancel", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              ),

            ],
          );
        }
    );
  }

  displayUploadScreen(){
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.5),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, color: Colors.grey,size: 200.0,),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.0),),
              child: Text("Upload Image", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),),
              color: Colors.green,
              onPressed: () => takeImage(context),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return displayUploadScreen();
  }
}
```

If you would like to see my code or other files I would like to share with you. Can you please guide me?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Ekin.

Comment: Hi Ekin, What dependencies are you using?

Comment: Hello, you can see my dependencies below and also I have added to my question above:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
  image: ^2.0.7
  animator: 0.1.4
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+7
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.3
  timeago: 2.0.17
  cached_network_image:
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  geolocator: 5.0.1
  uuid: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0
  firebase_storage: ^4.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.0

Comment: What device are you running on? e.g Emulator, phone

Comment: I am running on emulator which is Pixel 3a API 30 which has play services. By the way I have updated my question above. This additional information might help you.

Comment: At that point does it throw the error

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get the point. Can you specify the point and possible solution? Thanks you sou much for your helpfulness.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code
import 'dart:io';

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart'; // For File Upload To Firestore    
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';    
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart'; // For Image Picker    
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path; 

 class UploadImage extends StatelessWidget {
Future chooseFile() async {    
   await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery).then((image) {    
     setState(() {    
       _image = image;    
     });    
   });    
 }  
Future uploadFile() async {    
   StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance    
       .ref()    
       .child('posts/${Path.basename(_image.path)}}');    
   StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_image);    
   await uploadTask.onComplete;    
   print('File Uploaded');    
   storageReference.getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {    
     setState(() {    
       _uploadedFileURL = fileURL;    
     });    
   });    
 }  
    

@override    
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
   return Scaffold(    
     appBar: AppBar(    
       title: Text('Firestore File Upload'),    
     ),    
     body: Center(    
       child: Column(    
         children: <Widget>[    
           Text('Selected Image'),    
           _image != null    
               ? Image.asset(    
                   _image.path,    
                   height: 150,    
                 )    
               : Container(height: 150),    
           _image == null    
               ? RaisedButton(    
                   child: Text('Choose File'),    
                   onPressed: chooseFile,    
                   color: Colors.cyan,    
                 )    
               : Container(),    
           _image != null    
               ? RaisedButton(    
                   child: Text('Upload File'),    
                   onPressed: uploadFile,    
                   color: Colors.cyan,    
                 )    
               : Container(),    
           _image != null    
               ? RaisedButton(    
                   child: Text('Clear Selection'),    
                   onPressed: clearSelection,    
                 )    
               : Container(),    
           Text('Uploaded Image'),    
           _uploadedFileURL != null    
               ? Image.network(    
                   _uploadedFileURL,    
                   height: 150,    
                 )    
               : Container(),    
         ],    
       ),    
     ),    
   );
}
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, I guess this code is not suitable with my structure. Additionally, pickImage is not in use, we need to use getImage()

Answer (score 1):

The error seem to be appear because of null path by adding the null check `(if (imageFile != null))`
before accessing the path property, you can ensure the property access only when it is not null,

```dart
captureImageWithCamera() async {
  final currentContext = context;
  Navigator.pop(currentContext);
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  PickedFile? imageFile = await picker.getImage(
    source: ImageSource.camera,
    maxHeight: 680,
    maxWidth: 970,
  );
  if (imageFile != null) {
    imageFile = PickedFile(imageFile.path);
    setState(() {
      this.file = imageFile;
    });
  }
}
```

```dart
pickImageFromGallery() async {
  final currentContext = context;
  Navigator.pop(currentContext);
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  PickedFile? imageFile = await picker.getImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    maxHeight: 680,
    maxWidth: 970,
  );
  if (imageFile != null) {
    imageFile = PickedFile(imageFile.path);
    setState(() {
      this.file = imageFile;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to clean your project by the command `flutter clean` and rebuild it by the following command `flutter pub get`, and delete your app from the phone. hope it works for you.